# F# A type parameter is missing a constraint

Tags: generics, f#, type-constraints, type-parameter

I'm trying to define a generic addition operator for a wrapper class. So far I have this: (simplified from the actual code)

```
type Wrap<'a> =
    | Wrap of 'a
    static member inline (+) (Wrap x, Wrap y) = Wrap (x + y)

let inline addSelf x = x + x
```

and indeed it works:

```
let i = addSelf (Wrap 1)  // returns Wrap 2
let f = addSelf (Wrap 1.) // returns Wrap 2.0
```

but the following alternative to addSelf does not compile

```
let inline addSelf'  (Wrap x) = (Wrap x) + (Wrap x) // compile error
```

giving error FS0193: A type parameter is missing a constraint 'when ( ^a or  ^?15169) : (static member ( + ) :  ^a *  ^?15169 ->  ^?15170)'

Why does the more restricted addSelf' not work when addSelf works fine? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.  Consider sending it to fsbugs@microsoft.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the definition of Wrap in FSI, you will see that the static (+) operator is defined only for types that support the restriction, yet Wrap itself is defined for any types.

When write the first version, the type inference adds that restriction for you... but your second version allows any type for x (even for x that do not support the static (+) operator).

I.e. the second version suggest that it is possible to write a function that would support any type of Wrap<'T> although there's no guarantee 'T supports the + operator.

edit:
As Tomas pointed out, it's possible but you have to use a special syntax that defines which member to call, the following works:

```
let inline addSelf (x : Wrap<_>) =
    ((^a or ^b): (static member (+) : ^a * ^b -> ^c) (x,x))
```

Comment: +1 I think this is correct answer. It should still be possible to explicitly write `addSelf` with static constraints that restrict it to work only on `Wrap` types, but my head exploded when I tried to do that.

Comment: I think that makes sense. I was hoping the inference engine would work for both versions, allowing me to compile code that calls AddSelf' with a Wrap for a type that supports addition, but fail to compile if the type didn't support addition. Do you know why it wouldn't do this?

Comment: I'd like to know if I can cite where I found the solution. I'm not a usual poster as such I do not know if it's acceptable to advertise existing work.

Comment: Note that the above will fail at compile time if used on a type that doesn't support addition.

Comment: @TimC actually, your first version of addSelf does exactly that:
let inline addSelf x = x + x allows let v = addSelf (Wrap 12) but not let w = addSelf (Wrap (None : string option))

Comment: @David Thanks that seems to work :) I'm getting a warning about runtime failures, so I'll have a look into whether that's a problem or not! __warning FS0077: Member constraints with the name 'op_Addition' are given special status by the F# compiler as certain .NET types are implicitly augmented with this member. This may result in runtime failures if you attempt to invoke the member constraint from your own code.__

Comment: @David Oh yes, the first version works correctly, but in the real code I need to access the internals of the Wrap, so need the second version to work

Answer (score 4):

As I said in a comment, I think this is a bug.  Here's my reasoning.  When the compiler sees

```
let inline addSelf (Wrap x) = (Wrap x) + (Wrap x)
```

I think it should make roughly the following inferences:

1. The argument is of type `Wrap< ^t>` for some fresh `^t`.
2. Therefore `x` is of type `^t`.
3. Thus, the operands on the right hand side are also both of type `Wrap< ^t>`.
4. These values are being passed into the `(+)` operator.  Therefore, `Wrap< ^t>` needs to support a static operator `(+)` of type `Wrap< ^t> * Wrap< ^t> -> ^u` for some fresh type `^u`.
5. The only static operator `(+)` defined on `Wrap<_>` has type `Wrap< ^a> * Wrap< ^b> -> Wrap< ^c> when (^a or ^b) : (static member (+) : ^a * ^b -> ^c`.
6. Unifying type variables, the overall type of `addSelf` should be `addSelf : Wrap< ^t> -> Wrap< ^c> when ^t : (static member (+) : ^t * ^t -> ^c)`

The various type inference steps are tricky, so it's certainly possible that I'm missing something and this behavior is expected.  On the other hand, the various type inference steps are tricky, so they are a bit buggy :).  It's also concerning that you can't annotate the function and all subexpressions and get the code to compile:

```
let inline doStuff< ^t, ^u when ^t : (static member (+) : ^t * ^t -> ^u)> ((Wrap x) : Wrap< ^t>) : Wrap< ^u> =
    ((Wrap x) : Wrap< ^t>) + ((Wrap x) : Wrap< ^t>)
```

You still get a compiler error with the mysterious reference to the fresh type parameters `^?12020` and `^?12021` (or whatever the unique ints are in your case).  I think this shouldn't happen.

Comment: Thanks kvb, your explanation is much appreciated. I'll send in a bug report and see what they say.

Answer (score 0):

I think `addSelf'` should still be of the form

```
let inline addSelf' x = x + x
```

But with the correct type annotations:

```
let inline addSelf' (x : Wrap) = x + x
```

Or something similar to that. I'm a tad rusty on F# and can't test it right now.

Comment: let inline addSelf' (x : Wrap<'a>) = x + x gives the same compile error im afraid

Answer (score 0):

If you remove inline from the static (+) function i.e

```
type Wrap<'a> =
    | Wrap of 'a
    static member (+) (Wrap x, Wrap y) = Wrap (x + y)
```

Than it works fine.

I guess this is because in the `addSelf'` the compiler tries to find the + operator on Wrap type and as the + has been inlined it doesn't match the search criteria.

Comment: That contrains addition to work on one particular type of Wrap though, say, `Wrap<int>`

Comment: `addSelf' (Wrap "Hello")` also works... so it will work for any type which has + operator defined for it, also I dont think it make send to add Wrap<int> with Wrap<string>

Comment: I want to add `Wrap<int>` with other `Wrap<int>`s, and `Wrap<string>` with `Wrap<string>`s, but if I take away the `inline` I'll only be able to do one or the other, not both in the same program. Unless I've misunderstood your suggestion.

Comment: @TimC, you are correct it only works with one type without inline, whatever type is used first, seems the type infers uses the first usage of it to fix the types for whole application